# WIndows XP SP1 copy command in terminal not working

Tags: move, file-move

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>copy c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\accesschk.exe c:\Documents and Settings\
copy c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\accesschk.exe c:\Documents and Settings\
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

This has become very annoying as I see examples, and I see videos of yes, this is indeed the correct syntax. Im in the OSCP labs trying to move a file. The OS is Windows XP SP1. Can someone just tell me im a fool or I am going crazy.

Comment: have you tried to quote the parameters? 
`copy c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\accesschk.exe 'c:\Documents and Settings\'`

Comment: Yes. No luck. I also tried reversing the slashes.

Comment: why are there 2 copy commands in the same line?

Comment: Thats the error output repeating the command.

Comment: Maybe escaping the spaces: `copy c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\accesschk.exe c:\Documents\ and\ Settings`

Comment: Syntax error. I think it might be a permissions issue now since `C:\WINDOWS\system32>copy c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\accesschk.exe "c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop"
copy c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\accesschk.exe "c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop"
Access is denied.
        0 file(s) copied.`

Comment: The double quotes might be the key.